# I'm getting an error : Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, namespaces, game-development

I'm trying to switch scenes after a delay in unity. I keep getting the error message that

```
Type or namespace definition or end-of-file expected
```

This is my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

namespace Scene Management
{
    public class LoadNewscreen : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private float dalayBeforeLoding = 10f;
        [SerializeField]
        private string sceneNameToLoad;
        private float timeElapsed;


        private void Update()
        {
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timeElapsed > dalayBeforeLoding)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNameToLoad);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a very simple code honestly. But it just frustrates me that new errors keep popping up all the time. Does anyone have a solution to the problem I have? I'm a beginner so maybe it's something dumb.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the line `namespace Scene Management`. In C#, you cannot use spaces in a namespace name. Try changing the line to `namespace SceneManagement`.